# android image sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite

please i am trying to get the image of a url and save it in an sqlite db. and it is not working ... i am convert it to bitmap.
i dont really know about it . i have already created the sqlite table and i am using BlOB it works well when i get it from drawable...

this is the class.

package com.example.sqliteimagedemo;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SQLiteDemoActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ContactImageAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
        // get image from drawable
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2./demi.jpg");
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            // convert bitmap to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addContact(new Contact("GeekOnJava", imageInByte));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // display main List view bcard and contact name
 catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Reading all contacts from database
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
                    + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            // add contacts data in arrayList
            imageArry.add(cn);

        }
        adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list, imageArry);
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are your compressing a JPG (demi.jpg) to JPG (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG) again?

Comment: *Does not work* is --unfortunately-- not a very helpful problem description. Do you get any error message or exception? Have you tried checking the contents of your database file (by pulling it from the phone)?